# React pagination does not update page data when page number is changed

Tags: reactjs, pagination, react-table, reactstrap

I am new to react and I am using "ReactTable" Component to display data along with pagination. On changing the page, page number gets updated but data being displayed does not update (When page number is set from 1 to 2, table doesn't get updated to show next data from the second page). Also, changing number of rows doesn't work always. I understand that I will have to write a trigger function but I don't know how where and how to write one.

Here is how the pagination for the table looks like:
[Pagination image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIocP.png)

I came across a few custom pagination codes but they did not work. Also, I am interested in doing it with the built-in pagination code in  component.

```
    <ReactTable
         data={this.props.results.relations}
         minRows={0}
         showPagination={true}
         defaultPageSize={10}
         defaultFilterMethod={(filter, row) =>
              String(row[filter.id]).toLowerCase().includes(filter.value.toLowerCase())}
         columns={[
           {
             Header: "Column1",
             accessor: "col1",
             width: 70,
             filterMethod: (filter, rows) =>
             matchSorter(rows, filter.value, { keys: ["col1"] }),
             filterAll: true
           },
           {
             Header: "Column2",
             accessor: "col2",
             width: 150,
             filterMethod: (filter, rows) =>
             matchSorter(rows, filter.value, { keys: ["col2"] }),
             filterAll: true
           }
         ]} 
   />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add manual props in table to get updated data after callback and in onPageChange write your function which will set your new data

```
//In component Constructor
this.state{
   currentPage : 0;
   data : this.props.data,
   columns : [
           {
             Header: "Column1",
             accessor: "col1",
             width: 70,
             filterMethod: (filter, rows) =>
             matchSorter(rows, filter.value, { keys: ["col1"] }),
             filterAll: true
           },
           {
             Header: "Column2",
             accessor: "col2",
             width: 150,
             filterMethod: (filter, rows) =>
             matchSorter(rows, filter.value, { keys: ["col2"] }),
             filterAll: true
           }
         ]
}

changePage(pageIndex) {
   // setState new data in data variable
   // setState currentPage variable as well
}

// In render
    <ReactTable  
            className="custom-table column-larg-spacing"
                manual
                data={this.state.data}
                columns={this.state.columns} 
                defaultPageSize = {10}
                minRows = {0}
                resizable = {false} 
                page={this.state.currentPage}
                onPageChange={pageIndex => changePage(pageIndex)}
                pages = {5} // show total pages
                showPaginationBottom={true}
            />
```